# Search by date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my .aspx code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsVisitors" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
   SelectCommand="Visitors_Select_All" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtVisitorID" DbType="Int32" Name="VisitorID" PropertyName="Text"  DefaultValue="0" />

          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtName" Name="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"
                                DefaultValue="%" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlFloor" Name="Floor" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="%" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlLocation" Name="Location" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="%" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployee" DbType="Int32" Name="EmployeeID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                DefaultValue="0" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtMobile" Name="Mobile" PropertyName="Text"
                                ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="%" />
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFromDate" Name="FromDate" PropertyName="Text"
                              ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" DefaultValue="%" />
    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and my store procedure is

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Visitors_Select_All]
@VisitorID INT = 0 ,
@FirstName VARCHAR(30) = '' ,
@LastName VARCHAR(30) = '' ,
@City VARCHAR(30) = '' ,
@Floor VARCHAR(50) = '' ,
@Location VARCHAR(50) = '' ,
@Mobile VARCHAR(13) = '' ,
@EmployeeID INT = 0 ,
@FromDate VARCHAR(100) = ''
AS 
   BEGIN

    SELECT  V.[VisitorID] ,
            V.[FirstName] ,
            V.[MiddleName] ,
            V.[LastName] ,
            V.[Gender] ,
            V.[Age] ,
            V.[DetailWithMaterials] ,
            V.[City] ,
            V.[State] ,
            V.[PinCode] ,
            V.[Phone] ,
            V.[Mobile] ,
            V.[Date] ,
            V.Location ,
            E.Email
    FROM    [dbo].[Visitors] AS V
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] AS E ON V.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    WHERE   V.FirstName LIKE @FirstName + '%'
            AND V.LastName LIKE @LastName + '%'
            AND V.City LIKE @City + '%'
            AND V.[Floor] LIKE @Floor + '%'
            AND V.Location LIKE @Location + '%'
            AND V.Mobile LIKE @Mobile + '%'
            AND ( ( @VisitorID <> 0
                    AND V.VisitorID = @VisitorID
                  )
                  OR ( @VisitorID = 0 )
                )
            AND ( ( @EmployeeID <> 0
                    AND V.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
                  )
                  OR ( @EmployeeID = 0 )
                )
            AND ( ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), V.Date, 103) = @FromDate )
                  OR ( @FromDate = '' )
                )
    ORDER BY Date DESC

END
```

Now what i want is if i do not pass any parameter value then all record should be return and when i pass `@FromDate` then record of that date should be return. But this is not working now. If i remove `@FromDate` condition then it's working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug your procedure and see what parameters it is being passed?

Comment: For me query looks fine. But never do like this `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), V.Date, 103) = @FromDate` anymore. Compare date with date. Doing convertation `V.Date` to string you decrease speed of excecution your query. Because of this convertation index on `V.Date` cannot be use as it has to.

Answer (score 0):

Just based on your code, I have a suspicion the problem may be one of these:

1. `@FromDate` having either a time component, or being in the wrong format.  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), V.Date, 103)` would return the date '1/4/13' (April 1, 2013) as '01/04/2013', with a four digit year and leading zeroes.  So if what's passed in from `@FromDate` does not EXACTLY match that, you won't get a match.
2. The name of the parameter `@FromDate` implies that this is just the beginning of a date range, but your comparison is for an exact match.  So unless you have a record with `v.Date` exactly equal to `@FromDate`, you won't get any records.
3. Even if the problem above were fixed, you would be doing string comparisons, not date comparisons, so looking for records where `v.Date` was later than `@FromDate` would produce problems, because '02/01/2012' would be "later" that '01/04/2013'.  You'd get a random-appearing mishmash of records.

All of these would go away if you converted `@FromDate` to a date before doing your comparison:

```
DECLARE @fromDateAsDate date
IF @FromDate = ''
   SET @fromDateAsDate = NULL
ELSE
   SET @fromDateAsDate = CONVERT(date, @FromDate)

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE  (v.Date >= @FromDateasDate or @FromDateAsDate IS NULL)
```

You would also get better performance:  MikkaRin is entirely right about that.  This is not because converting types is expensive (though it can be), it's because the query engine can't optimize based on indexes if the fields in the index being compared are inside expressions (like your conversion) rather than jut used as they are.